# Incorrectly displayed reputation at Profile page - Accounts

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, profile-page, user-accounts

The displayed reputation at the `Accounts` tab of the [summary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w) is inconsistently wrong.

### Steps to reproduce

1. Visit the [Accounts tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w?tab=accounts) - The displayed reputation is equal to the displayed reputation at the separate sites. **= Expected**
2. Visit the [Summary tab, Accounts section](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w) - Same numbers as at `1.` **= Expected**
3. *Wait a while (a couple of minutes, estimated max at 10)*
4. Refresh the [Summary tab, Accounts section](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w) - SU drops to 1 reputation **= Not expected**

## Update: The latest occurrence of this bug (1 february 2012)

Yesterday, I joined SU. I started at 146 reputation, because of a migrated answer (4 months earlier). At the Accounts tab, however, the shown reputation is **101**:
[image]

---

*Have a look at the [revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/114169/revisions) for the previous occurrence of this bug.*

Comment: Sorry - not a duplicate of the question I linked to

Comment: @Bobby I am always able to reproduce this bug in multiple browsers, across all SE websites.

Comment: I don't know if what I'm seeing is related. Anyway, my rep on Code Review is 126, but the Accounts summary consistently shows 111.

Comment: @Costique That one seems to be related. Using exactely the same procedure (see question), I changed 111 to 126, at your user profile.