# Accounts panel reporting incorrect reputation from other stack exchange sites with new accounts

Tags: bug, status-completed

I'm a somewhat regular user of Stack Overflow. Recently, I opened accounts on the [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) sites. I linked my accounts, and the new accounts were each given a reputation bonus (which I believe is the expected behaviour when an experienced Stack Overflow user creates new accounts on other sites).

Visting the headers on all three sites reports my reputation as

- 3380 on StackOverflow
- 101 on Meta
- 101 on Programmers

However, when I visit my profile pages on the sites, the reputations listed in the "Accounts" don't always match these values:

- Each site reports the correct reputation for itself.
- Each site reports the correct reputation for Stack Overflow.
- Meta reports that my Programmers reputation is 1.
- Programmers reports that my Meta reputation is 1.

Could this be a bug?

### Screenshots

The accounts section for [my profile on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8313/sean-reilly):

[image: Accounts section from Stack Overflow]

And for [my profile on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/178917/sean-reilly):

[image: Accounts section from Meta]

And for [my profile on Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/47770/sean-reilly):

[image]

### Caching

I don't think this is a caching issue because:

- It's been this way for quite some time (over a week).
- The other sites are updating changes to my Stack Overflow reputation fairly quickly.
- When I earned a badge on meta, it propagated to the other sites quickly — I'd assume that badges and reputation are probably cached together.

### Update

Creating this question has earned me reputation on Meta. My Meta reputation is now reported consistently (121 at the moment) across all three sites.

Comment: I've noticed that problem. I think it started 17 Feb (+/- a day).

Comment: @Nick: My meta account was created on Feb 14th — I've seen the issue since then.

Comment: I would wager that the cache does not have expire time, rather it's refreshed only upon certain actions - [your first real action here on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/178917/sean-reilly?tab=activity) was only one hour ago and it triggered cache refresh and now your reputation is displayed correctly all over. The 100 rep bonus from associating accounts is not considered action thus not causing cache refresh.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: that seems accurate. I would think that possible improvement might be to add a cache refresh trigger to the "100 bonus reputation" grant.

Comment: Not a [developer](http://stackexchange.com/about/team) so don't know for sure, hope one will show up to confirm. Your suggestion sounds good as well. :)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: Also, I earned a badge (for upvoting another answer) that didn't trigger a cache refresh. I saw the bronze badge on Stack Overflow with a reputation of 1. Of course, that might just mean that badges and rep are cached separately.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: I had triggered a rep recalc on Meta (a week ago) but on SO I still see wrong Meta rep.

Comment: @Nick yep saw that now - 200 "ghost" points! (Likely bounty granted to you on a now deleted answer?) Just for "debug" sake, try posting answer or question and see if this really refresh the cache.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: yeap, I lost a bounty!

Comment: @Nick you made me curious.. can you post dummy answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) then delete it shortly after, just to see if this really refresh the cache? :)

Comment: @Nick I see [you just did](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123099) - so looks like only posting a question force "hard refresh" of the cache all over the network.. :/

Comment: This is the result of issues with aggreation and concurrent database locks...we're fixing the underlying issue before backfilling with correct data.

Comment: @NickCraver I have seen this bug [before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114169/incorrectly-displayed-reputation-at-profile-page-accounts). Also, do you know what's going on with [**this bug**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122218/wrong-answer-count-at-accounts-tab)? Also a "database issue"?

Comment: @NickCraver: just checked this again, and it's fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue with my ask ubuntu account. I think when you open an account and do nothing with it other Q&A don't reflect the 100 rep bonus.