# Error when displaying reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incorrectly displayed reputation at Profile page - Accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114169/incorrectly-displayed-reputation-at-profile-page-accounts)
>   [Why is one profile-page showing one rep, while another profile page is showing another rep for the same account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130940/why-is-one-profile-page-showing-one-rep-while-another-profile-page-is-showing-a)

When I connect from my metastackoverflow account, viewing the Accounts part I have noticed that my stackoverflow reputation is not the same as when i connect to my stackoverflow account. Also it's about three hours now since I noticed this, can it be related to propagation on servers? Could someone explain why this error occur ?

**Connected from metaStackOverflow:**
[image]

**connected from StackOverflow:**
[image]

Comment: See [Why is one profile-page showing one rep, while another profile page is showing another rep for the same account?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130940)

Answer (score 0):

It may be taking a while to propagate across the servers.  (I've noticed the same thing happening in SO chat).  Try refreshing without cache (`ctrl` + `f5`).  If that doesn't work, wait five minutes.

Comment: Yes I think it's related to propagation across servers, but it's about 3 hours since I noticed this

Comment: I've noticed the same thing more than 12 hours ago, and it's still there.